# Swift and Firebase: Closures race condition

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures, race-condition

I need to call a closure within a closure and avoid the race condition.

Currently, I have a class named as **FirebaseUtilities** that includes all the code that has to do with calling Firebase and retrieve data.

### App logic

An article has a lot of data, like title, summary, body, subjects, etc. The subjects are linked to the article using this convention:

[image]

In this class I have a function that fetches the articles:

### Closure for fetching articles

```
func fetchArticles(completion: @escaping ([Article]?, Error?) -> Void) {

    var subjects = [Subject]()

    Database.database().reference().child("articles").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        // in here i get the value of the snapshot and from there i extract the key of each subject and i store it in an array of String (ex. ["-MD4tN_AjPuCvTUEyZyL"])

        // then I call another closure that is responsible for fetching the subjects based on the UID of each subject (see below)
    }
    
})
```

### Closure for fetching subjects

```
func fetchSubjects(subjectsUids: [String], completion: @escaping ([Subject]?, Error?) -> Void) {
    
    var subjects = [Subject]()
    
    subjectsUids.forEach { (subjectUid) in
        self.dbSubjectsRef.child(subjectUid).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let subjectDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            
            let subject = Subject(dictionary: subjectDictionary)
            
            subjects.append(subject)
            
            completion(subjects, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

Subjects array will always be an empty array since it will always be faster than fetching data from Firebase:

```
func fetchArticles(completion: @escaping ([Article]?, Error?) -> Void) {

    var subjects = [Subject]()

    Database.database().reference().child("articles").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        // in here i get the value of the snapshot and from there i extract the key of each subject and i store it in an array of String (ex. ["-MD4tN_AjPuCvTUEyZyL"])

        // then I call another closure that is responsible for fetching the subjects based on the UID of each subject

        self.fetchSubjects(subjectsUids: subjectsUids) { (subjectsResults, error) in
            guard let sub = subjectsResults else { return }
            subjects = sub
            
            // (A) printing here **shows desired results**
            print(subjects)
         }

         // (B) printing here **does not show the results**
         // it returns an empty array []
         print(subjects)
    }    
})
```

### What I want:

I need to get the array of subjects outside the second closure (self.fetchSubjects(....)).

Any ideas on how to resolve this kind of race condition?

Comment: Here's the issue *// then I call another closure* - why? You already have that data in the first closure? Why go back and get the data you already have? Either a) nest reading the subject within the first closure so it only reads after the article is read or b) use a DispatchQueue to go read all of the subjects after all of the articles are loaded. Again though, you're creating a lot of extra work for yourself - just nest reading that articles subjects in the first closure much like what you're doing. There's no race condition there as data is valid within the closure.

Comment: Oh. It's not clear why you're doing this `var subjects = [Subject]()` but don't initialize it each time - that erases the array. simply append data to it e.g. make it a class array. let me know if you need example code.

Comment: @Jay, I dont have the data in the first closure, just the UIDs of the data i want. To get the actual data i will need to initiate another Firebase call and use the appropriate UID to get the object with all the data.

Comment: The clarify, in the main function that reads the articles/subject id's, you have all of the article data and then the subject ID you want. So, just read it there. There's no need to read all of the articles and then separately read all of the subjects - that's what's causing the 'race condition'. Alternately you could use dispatch to queue your functions in order but that's probably overkill. Also, I will mention it again, doing this `var subjects = [Subject]()` inside your function will make subjects only exist inside the function. You should be populating a class var, not local.

Comment: @Jay I do var subjects = [Subject]() is because I need to store the subjects somewhere and later use them to build my article struct. Also, I am not using class var, as I created a dedicated Firebase utilities class that I call in my view controllers like so: FirebaseUtilities().fetchArticles { ... }. This way I can very easily maintain the code for Firebase instead of going from one VC to another and change the code. In the same manner, I am trying to use a separate closure for each node (subjects, authors, etc) and use these closures inside fetchArticles closure. Hope it makes some sense.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your 'Firebase utility' would generally be a singleton pattern that contains firebase functions. The actual data that's retrieved would need to be stored somewhere and that would typically be an array, and often times a class var that can be accessed by all of the dataSource and delegate functions within the class.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the array of subjects outside the second closure (self.fetchSubjects(....)).

That is not possible: any code that needs the subject will need to be inside the closure, or be called from there.

If you want to use the list of subjects elsewhere, you can do what you've done with the `fetchSubjects` function: pass in a callback that is then called when the subjects have been loaded.

Also see these other [questions about asynchronously loading data from Firebase in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+asynchronous).